# UITextView font to always be fixed size

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell, uifont

I have a `UICollectionView` with cells sized to the same aspect ratio as a4 page. And with different screen sizes I would like for that text to be sized at fixed 12pt (that would be calculated to that `UICollectionview` cell), which would look bigger on the iPad and smaller on iPhone.

So having a fixed font size isn't an option...

[image: Hope it would add more clearance]

Comment: Do u want increase your. textview's font size as per mobile size right ?

Comment: @McDonal_11 I've added ant image, hope it would make more sense :)

Comment: Using Storyboard ? Autolayout? Costraints?

Comment: No storyboards. Actually saving frame/bounds rect and setting those in cellForItem

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: If it is ok, then kindly accept this answer and upvote this.

Comment: If u r satisfy, kindly accept this answer and upvote too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Coding**

```
var fontSize : CGFloat = 12.0 // DEFAULT SIZE
```

In your ViewDidLoad

```
if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
    switch self.view.frame.size.height {
    case 480:
        fontSize = 12.0
    case 568:
        fontSize = 14.0
    case 667:
        fontSize = 16.0
    case 736:
        fontSize = 17.0
    case 812:
        fontSize = 18.0
    default:
        print("unknown")
    }
}
else if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {

    fontSize = 20.0

}
```

Then apply this `fontSize`, wherever u need.

**Storyboard**

Select UITextView, in `Attributes Inspector` area, + (plus) symbol is near to `Font`. By default it will work for `iPhone` devices. For `iPad`, Change change size classes to Regular width and Regular Height **wR hR** . For, that U can increase font size.

[image]