# How can i set dynamic font in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, uifont

I am using **"Automatic adjust font"** property of `UILabel`, It working fine with TextStyles - "Body", "callout", "Headline" etc.
but not works with system font.

Is that "Automatic adjust font" only works with above [Textstyles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIZH8.png)?

Comment: if u want do it manually, use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630776/uitextview-font-to-always-be-fixed-size/48646121#48646121

Comment: Any better way? is it Possible Directly from Storyboard?

Comment: Font size or font ?

Comment: " Font" should be dynamic  as  works fine with TextStyles - "Body", "callout", "Headline"

Answer (score 0):

```
 extension UILabel {
        open override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            self.setup()
        }

        func setup() {
            let size = self.font.pointSize*widthFactor
            self.font = UIFont.init(name: self.font.fontName, size: size)
            if self.attributedText != nil {
                let str = self.attributedText
                self.attributedText = str
            }else{
                 let str = self.text
                 self.text = str
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: use macro file and make this extension
widthFactor = SCREEN_WIDTH/320.0